Dots in beamer miniframe
I am creating a presentation in Beamer, and I am using the following code:
\documentclass[
    8pt, % Set the default font size, options include: 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, 20pt
    %t, % Uncomment to vertically align all slide content to the top of the slide, rather than the default centered
    aspectratio=169, % Uncomment to set the aspect ratio to a 16:9 ratio which matches the aspect ratio of 1080p and 4K screens and projectors
]{beamer}

\graphicspath{{img/}} % Specifies where to look for included images (trailing slash required)
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetheme{CamridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

My problem is the following: in the miniframe, below the name of each section, there are only 6 dots, even though the length of the name of the section would allow putting more dots. Then, the dot number 7 of the section is put in a second line below the first 6 dots, and so on. I am wondering if there is a way to allow more dots on the same line, as much as the length of the name of the section allows.
I would be very thankful if someone could help me...

Please always make a short but compilable test document, including a document environment and a basic document which actually reproduces your problem.

Many of the packages you have are not necessary for a beamer presentation. You should only load the packages which you need for this specific document. This will avoid clashes between packages.

Normally, the miniframes of each subsection are on a separate line. You can use the compress option to switch this off and have them all in the same line:
\documentclass[
    8pt,
    aspectratio=169,
    compress
]{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thank you very much, now it works as I want!

@Stefano You're welcome!
